# oc command not found in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, openshift, gitlab-ci-runner

i am trying to set some environment variables in my openshift container with the following job in gitlab

```
deploy_dev:
  image: devops/bob:${BOB_VERSION}
  only:
    - main
  dependencies:
    - build_publish
  script:
    - >
      oc login --token=$OCP4_DEPLOYER_TOKEN
      oc project $CI_PROJECT_NAME-$env
      oc set env dc/openshift-traefik ENVIRONMENT=dev
      oc logout
```

but i am getting the following error: `/usr/bin/bash: line 176: oc: command not found` and i am not too sure how should i fix this

Answer (score 0):

The image devops/bob:${BOB_VERSION} doesn't contain oc, you can:

- choose another image with oc installed
- add oc in devops/bob creating another one image.

You can find a docker image with the oc at https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin-cli